# Google Storage:: Clicking on "Public Link" downloads the files

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I am referring below Github link,

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/json-api/src/main/java/StorageSample.java

Code Snippet

```
public static void uploadFile(String bucketName, String targetPath, String filePath) throws Exception {
    Storage storage = getStorage();
    StorageObject object = new StorageObject();
    object.setBucket(bucketName);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        // String contentType =
        // URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
        InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent("image/jpeg", stream);
        Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(bucketName, null, content);
        insert.setName(targetPath + file.getName());
        insert.execute();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}

public static void uploadFile(String name, String targetPath, String contentType, File file, String bucketName)
        throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, Exception {
    InputStreamContent contentStream = new InputStreamContent(contentType, new FileInputStream(file));
    contentStream.setLength(file.length());
    StorageObject objectMetadata = new StorageObject().setName(targetPath + name)
            .setAcl(Arrays.asList(new ObjectAccessControl().setEntity("allUsers").setRole("READER")));

    Storage client = getStorage();
    Storage.Objects.Insert insertRequest = client.objects().insert(bucketName, objectMetadata, contentStream);
    insertRequest.execute();
}

private static Storage getStorage() throws Exception {
    if (storage == null) {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);
        // Collection<String> scopes = StorageScopes.all();
        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setServiceAccountId(getProperties().getProperty(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File(getProperties().getProperty(PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_PROPERTY)))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

        storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(getProperties().getProperty(APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY)).build();
    }
    return storage;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // CloudStorage.createBucket("my-bucket3/good");

        CloudStorage.uploadFile("my-static", "temp/",
                "/Users/rupanjan/Downloads/15676285_10158033346085311_1317913818452680683_o.jpg");

        CloudStorage.uploadFile("15676285_10158033346085311_1317913818452680683_o.jpg", "temp/", "image/jpeg",
                new File("/Users/rupanjan/Downloads/15676285_10158033346085311_1317913818452680683_o.jpg"),
                "my-static");

        // CloudStorage.downloadFile("my-bucket", "some-file.jpg",
        // "/var/downloads");

        List<String> buckets = CloudStorage.listBuckets();
        System.out.println(buckets.size());
    }
```

### The issue I am facing,

I am able to upload the file successfully, but whenever, I click on that "Public Link", it downloads automatically. My intention was to share it for all user with read access.
N.B. If I am uploading the file manually from browser, I am able to open the file in browser, but when I upload it programically, it downloads everytime I click on "Public Link"

Please correct me if I am missing anything!!

Comment: Well, depends on your browser, but typically right clicking on the link and selecting "copy link address" will make the "public link" available to paste it somewhere else.

Comment: I tried the same thing .. it downloads from another window too .. :(

Comment: "Copy link address" really, really shouldn't download anything. Are you sure you didn't hit "Save link as" or "Open in new tab"? Copy link address works fine for me..

Comment: Ah, that wasn't at all clear in your comment.

Comment: Both render the image for me, btw.

Comment: Yes ... @JonSkeet .. it's working ... my bad .. Thanks a ton
But .. do I have to "Copy link address" everytime to make the link work??
... because I will be uploading images in bulk and be accessing those with  urls created programmatically ..!!

Comment: @JonSkeet The link still downloads when I am in the same browser logged in GCP account .... in private window, it is rendering properly...is that an issue?

Comment: I can't tell whether it's an issue for you or not. The "copy link address" is only as *one way* of getting at the public URL. You can get at it programmatically as well. It's not really clear what you're asking at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you know the name of the bucket and the object, and that the objects are all publicly readable, and that you want a URL that you can share that will allow others to read the object.

There is no need to use the "public link" functionality in the console for this. Public URLs can be constructed programmatically. They follow this pattern:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name
```